# Problem with Ofbiz and ftl templates

Tags: ofbiz

i'm new to Ofbiz, and i'm trying this [HelloWorld tutorial](http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/hello_world1.php).

I am using Ofbiz 10.04 and the error i'm getting is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template component://common/webcommon/includes/htmlTemplate.ftl not found.
```

I searched Google and all i found were pages with SVN commits. Can someone help me? Is there something wrong with my Ofbiz configuration?

htmlTemplate.ftl is here:

```
$ ls -l framework/common/webcommon/includes/htmlTemplate.ftl
-rw-r--r-- 1 pacorg users 4988 2011-04-08 10:25 framework/common/webcommon/includes/htmlTemplate.ftl
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: not sure if it's a permission problem for the files on linux - it works on Windows okay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i solved it.

On `controller.xml`, i changed:

```
<view-map name="main" type="ftl" page="main.ftl"/>
```

To:

```
<view-map name="main" type="ftl" page="component://hello1/webapp/hello1/main.ftl"/>
```

And now it works.

I hope it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
<view-map name="main" type="ftl" page="component://hello1/webapp/hello1/main.ftl"/>
```

worked for us.For specifying the ".ftl" file use absolute path.